# More refined Chrome Proxy settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I need Chrome to use a SOCKS proxy to *.example.com except local.example.com . This doesn't seem to be possible from the standard settings. Is there perhaps an extension or something that could achieve this?

Comment: chrome use internet explorer settings you can set it up to socks proxy for all addresses except the ones you want ill post how to do it in minute unless you figure it out yourself

Comment: I am using Linux and there's no IE in sight (phew!).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a file somewhere:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  if (/\.example\.com$/.test(host) && host != 'local.example.com') {
    return "SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:8000";
  }
  return "DIRECT";
}
```

Then in Chrome proxy settings pick "proxy autoconfiguration URL" and then there's a small disk icon, click it and pick the file.

I do not think there's a good way to avoid PAC.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses the operating system's proxy settings. For example, you can set the proxy settings in Windows to point to your SOCKS server while excluding certain domains

[image: Windows SOCKS proxy settings]

For more fine-grained control to sites and domains, you will need to use a proxy with PAC. For example, [pacproxy](https://github.com/williambailey/pacproxy) or Shawdowsocks.